# How do I ignore Destination collection type property when mapping using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm mapping from an input model (source) to a domain model (destination)

The destination class has a list of objects of a type and that type has properties which are *not* on the source list type

This is causing the following exception

> AutoMapperConfigurationException: Unmapped members were found. Review
> the types and members below.

Oddly enough, no exceptions are throw when the input models collection object type has a property which is not contained within the domain models collection object type. Its only the other way around.

How can I ensure that properties can exist on the domain models collection object type which are not mapped to anything?

Here is MRE
https://github.com/jstallm/AutomapperListIssue-MRE

In this MRE, you can see that the input model has list of type Class1InputModel. Class1InputModel has a property of Description which automapper does not complain about at all.

However, the class DomainModel has a list of type Class1DomainModel which contains field named Other. This is the only property causing issues. Essentially upon successfully mapping, I want the property "Other" to be null.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore this list :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.SpecialProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Other options is to add map for the list item  type of each one and ignore only the list type missing  properties and then you dont need to ignore the list in the parents mapping, for example :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>();

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceListItemsType, DestinationListItemsType>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.SpecialProperty1, opt => opt.Ignore()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.SpecialProperty2, opt => opt.Ignore()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.SpecialProperty3, opt => opt.Ignore()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.SpecialProperty4, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Can you look at the MRE I created here and let me know if this applies? https://github.com/jstallm/AutomapperListIssue-MRE

Comment: you should create map for Class1InputModel, and ignore properties

Comment: Mapper.CreaeMap<Class1InputModel, Class1DomainModel>()
 .ForMember(dst => dst.Other, opt => opt.Ignore());

Answer (score 3):

The place where you define mapping, like

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

You can ignore the specific field under below

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.Destination, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Can you look at the MRE I created here and let me know if this applies? https://github.com/jstallm/AutomapperListIssue-MRE

Comment: I've looked your code there is only one thing you should do is; "CreateMap<InputModel, DomainModel>()" change it as => CreateMap<InputModel, DomainModel>(x => x.Destination, opt => opt.Ignore());

Comment: I am using the Automapper 11.0.1 and out of 100 properties in destination type, I was getting error for one int? property which was not even defined in mapping but somehow Automapper was trying to map it and second line in your solution is useful to ignore specific property on destination type to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is no longer thrown just by the virtue of creating a simple mapping between the lists themselves. No ignores needed.

Just add a profile for the lists themselves
[image]

Then ensure it is added to mapperconfiguration

[image]

Comment: see my answer, and the comments